# SSH Key: “Permissions 0644 for 'id_rsa.pub' are too open.” on mac

Tags: ssh, permissions, key

I generate a ssh key pair on my mac and add the public key to my ubuntu server(in fact, it is a virtual machine on my mac),but when I try to login the ubuntu server,it says:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa.pub
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I have tried many ways to solve this, change the key file mode, change the folder mode,as some answer on stackoverflow,but it doesn't work.
the key file permission:

```
vm dir:
drwxr-xr-x   4 tudouya  staff    136  4 29 10:37 vm

key file:
-rw-------  1 tudouya  staff  1679  4 29 10:30 vm_id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 tudouya  staff   391  4 29 10:30 vm_id_rsa.pub
```

please give me some idea...
=========================================
I write the host infomation to ssh_config:

```
Host ubuntuvm
    Hostname 10.211.55.17
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa.pub
```

I run command "ssh -v ubuntuvm",it displays:

```
ssh -v ubuntuvm
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 103: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 175: Applying options for ubuntuvm
debug1: Connecting to 10.211.55.17 [10.211.55.17] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa.pub type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-8 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 55:6d:4f:0f:23:51:ac:8e:70:01:ec:0e:62:9e:1c:10
debug1: Host '10.211.55.17' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/tudouya/.ssh/known_hosts:54
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa.pub
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa.pub
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the specific ssh command that you're running? If the key file in question is specified in the ssh config file, please include the relevant line(s) from the config file as well.

Comment: To me was "bad permissions"

Comment: I face this problem when add `-i id_rsa.pub` at the ssh command use for connection. Seems that enforcing to use some public key on the ssh command force to ask for password (even when the passphrase was empty, at least on my case)

Comment: It's actually insane that these guys take the effort to print that message, including the current permission value, but don't tell you what should the permission be. It's like a "I could tell you, but this is Linux, so I'll keep it cryptic so you have to Google and waste time" attitude.

Comment: @DiegoAndrésDíazEspinoza  for ssh -i you should  specify a private key.  For ssh-copy-id -i you should specify a public key!  what's happening for you is you are doing ssh and specifying a public key(wrong move), and it thinks you're specifying a private key , uses it as a private key, that then fails so it asks for a password cos the ssh server is set to allow passwords when keys don't work

Answer (score 291, accepted):

```
debug1: identity file /Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa.pub type 1
```

It appears that you're trying to use the wrong key file. The file with the ".pub" extension contains the *public* portion of the key. The corresponding file without the ".pub" extension contains the *private* part of the key. When you run an ssh client to connect to a remote server, you have to provide the private key file to the ssh client.

You probably have a line in the your `.ssh/config` file (or `/etc/ssh_config`) which looks like this:

```
IdentityFile .../.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa.pub
```

You need to remove the ".pub" extension from the filename:

```
IdentityFile .../.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa
```

Comment: I was having this problem with SQLPro and had incorrectly selected the public (`.pub`) file instead of the private file.

Comment: I got this error when I did `ssh -i id_ed25519.pub` whereas doing `ssh -i id_ed25519` works

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. @Rick Benetti's answer is simpler and applies to more situations.

Comment: Big thank! The real purpose, none of the suggested worked for me. The problem reproduces only on WSL2 while working on Ubuntu18 with *.pub

Comment: this Doesn't work.
I am following the documentation at https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent.

And i am getting the same error as op mentioned. And this solution doesn't work for me

Comment: @akshitbhatia This question is about using the file with the ".pub" extension as the private key file. If you're using the correct key file--the one without the .pub extension--then this question isn't relevant to you.

Comment: Note that there is actually a valid usecase for providing the public key to the `IdentitiesFile` parameter: if the private key is provided by an agent then specifying the public key can help ssh pick the correct key and (if `IdentitiesOnly yes` is specified) *only* present that one to the target server. Unfortunately even in this case SSH requires the permissions to be fit for a private key.

Answer (score 1382):

I suggest you to do:

```
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: `“Permissions 0644 for 'id_rsa.pub' are too open."` and the key was hence ignored. This was probably because i copied the key-file, from my another PC. But fixing permissions fixed the issue. thx!

Comment: @xoxn--1'w3k4n Why is this so bad? It makes sense if people copied or otherwise poorly managed their read-write access to these sensitive files, that they should be fixed.

Comment: This is not duct tape. If you copied over your ids, this makes sense.

Comment: Worked for me as a solution when copying ssh keys from old computer!

Comment: Works on WSL too

Comment: I made this change on both the id_rsa.pub and id_rsa files and found this solved the problem for me. I also ensured the IdenetityFile in my config pointed at id_rsa

Answer (score 107):

Key should be readable by the logged in user.

Try this:

```
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/Key_file
```

Comment: With public key 400 or 600 I get invalid format doing `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub `

Comment: @rhand ssh-add needs the private key not the public one

Answer (score 85):

```
chmod 400 path/to/filename
```

This work for me. When I did this file I am able to connect to my EC2 instance

Answer (score 62):

change your KEY permission to

chmod 400 your_key.pem

It should work !

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-chmod-numeric-permissions-notation-command/

Answer (score 32):

After running below command it works for me

```
sudo chmod 600 /path/to/my/key.pem
```

Answer (score 22):

In my case, it was a .pem file. Turns out holds good for that too. Changed permissions of the file and it worked.

`chmod 400 ~/.ssh/dev-shared.pem`

Thanks for all of those who helped above.

Answer (score 21):

SSH keys are meant to be private so a `644` permission is too open.

Binary references to set Permissions

```
 r(read) = 4
 w(write) = 2
 x(execute) = 1
```

So by adding these numbers and by passing the summed digit to chmod command,We set the permission of file/directory.
The first digit sets permission for the owner, second digit for group and the third one for all other users on the system who have no right to the file.

```
A permission of 644 means 
(4+2) = read/write permission for the owner
(4) = read permission for the group 
(4) = read permission for all other users
```

By changing the the permission of the file to `400` using

```
chmod 400 <filename>
```

solves the issue. As it makes the key read-only accessible to the owner.

Ref: https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/understanding-linux-file-permissions/

Comment: if you are already using the private file (not the .pub file) then this is the right solution just chmod 400 id_rsa_privatefilename and try to connect again

Comment: Nice answer :o)

Answer (score 17):

Lot's of similar answers but no explanations...

The error is thrown because the private key file permissions are too open. It is a security risk.

Change the permissions on the private key file to be minimal (read only by owner)

1. Change owner `chown <unix-name> <private-key-file>`
2. Set minimal permissions (read only to file owner) `chmod 400 <private-key-file>`

Answer (score 17):

```
chmod 600 id_rsa
```

Run above command from path where key is stored in vm ex: `cd /home/opc/.ssh`

Comment: 600 gives read and write permission.

Answer (score 16):

If the keys are in the ~/.ssh directory , use

chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

If the keys are in different directory, use

chmod 400 directory_path/id_rsa

This worked for me.

Comment: How does this improve the other answers?

Comment: it is not the pub key that must be protected, is the private one

Comment: The private key has to be protected.

Comment: **It works for me.** I think `chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` this is what you meant @Anirban.  As stated above: **The file with the ".pub" extension is the public key file. The corresponding file without the ".pub" extension is the private key file.** We need to protect private one.

Comment: Edited the answer. It should be the private key.

Comment: `chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` worked very well!

Answer (score 16):

I have similar issue and solved it by changing the permission of the respective files and folder worked for me.

This is the solution which is worked for me:

```
$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
```

Comment: the shorthand: 

```
$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/*
$ chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to run the command bellow

```
chmod 400 /path/to/my/key.pem
```

Answer (score 7):

As for me, the default mode of `id_rsa` is `600`, which means `readable` and `writable`.

After I push this file to a git repo and pull it from another pc, sometimes the mode of the private key file becomes `-rw-r--r--`.

When I pull the repo with ssh after specify the private key file, it failed and prompted warnings  the same with you. Following is my script.

```
ssh-agent bash -c "ssh-add $PATH_OF_RSA/id_rsa; \
git pull git@gitee.com:someone/somerepo.git "
```

I fix this problem just by changing the mode to `600`.

```
chmod 600 $PATH_TO_RSA/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 7):

This problem had a quick and easy fix. You just had to change the permissions on the pem file using the following command.

`chmod 400 /Users/yourUserName/pathOfYourFile/fileName.pem`

This command will make the file read only and remove all other permissions on the file

Answer (score 6):

giving permision 400 makes the key private and not accessible by someone unknown. It makes the key as a protected one.

```
chmod 400 /Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa.pub
```

Answer (score 5):

If youre using a .ssh/config file try to

```
chmod 0400 .ssh/config
```

then:

```
chmod 0400 .ssh/<<KEYFILE_PATH>>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just run below to your pem's

```
sudo chmod 600 /path/to/my/key.pem
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
chmod 600 id_rsa
```

Comment: request to call ```chmod 600 blah``` is not descriptive enough; as noted in an earlier comment, you need to run this command *in the location where the key is stored*

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue with a macbook m1, I later realized that i was missing `sudo` from the connection script

```
sudo ssh -i "key.pem" ubuntu@IP_Address
```

Ensure you are not missing the `sudo` in your connection script if you are using a macbook.

Answer (score 3):

Those who suggested chmod 400 id_rsa.pub did not sound right at all. It was quite possible that op used pub key **instead of** private key to ssh.

So it might be as simple as `ssh -i /Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa (the private key) user@host` to fix it.

--- update ---

Check this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2 for how to set up ssh key

Comment: Could be, although in my case when I searched for this issue and got to the answer the chmod 400 was what I needed to solve my problem. Thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 2):

`chmod 400 /etc/ssh/*` works for me.

Comment: You can do this so long as you realize you're affecting all keys in the directory.

Answer (score -1):

i had similar issues and this was what i did and it worked.

sudo ssh -i webhost.pem ubuntu@ipaddress

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72498290/2227743).

Answer (score -2):

There has been a lot of great explanation above, so I recommend reading and understanding.

Here is my simple step by step solution:

1. On your terminal, run:
   `open ~/.ssh/config`
2. In your file, you will see something similar to this (in my personal case):

```
Host *
  IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

or like this (as per the example in this question).

```
Hostname 10.211.55.17
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa.pub
```

3. Remove the ".pub" extention from the last line, which should look like:

```
Hostname 10.211.55.17
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa
```

or in my case:

```
Host *
  IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

4. Save the file and test your ssh connection.

Answer (score -12):

I removed the `.pub file`, and it worked.

Comment: Removing the .pub file is not necessary. It will also mean you don't have a record of the public key on your machine for later use.

Comment: If you have OpenSSH, you can regenerate the missing public key file from the private key by using `ssh-keygen -i -f /path/to/private.key > /desired/path/to/public.key`.  So, it's not really lost. :)