# gcloud: permission denied (public key) when ssh-ing to server

Tags: authentication, ssh, instance, gcloud, public-key

I am trying to set up a new ssh key for a gcloud instance. I followed the instructions here verbatim (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys), generating a new key, putting the public rsa-ssh key with my username on the SSH Keys section of the Metadata tab in the Google Cloud Platform interface, and setting the appropriate permissions for my public and private keys with chmod.

I am getting an error which ends as follows, when attempting to ss using the -vvv verbose flag:

...

`debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/erickofman/.ssh/salsadb
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).`

I have (with a co-worker) ensured that my public key is contained within the authorized_keys file in the server's .ssh folder. Thinking that perhaps something was just stale, I also tried restarting the ssh server using `service sshd restart` to no avail.

I also tried setting up ssh using the gcloud tool, same result.

I have the correct role/permissions for the site from what I can tell.

This is what the log looks like on the server side:

`admin@awesome-website:~$ tail  /var/log/auth.log
Nov 15 20:40:16 awesome-website sshd[18846]: input_userauth_request: invalid user ekofman [preauth]
Nov 15 20:40:17 awesome-website sshd[18846]: Connection closed by 10.100.100.10 port 90001 [preauth]
Nov 15 20:41:17 awesome-website sshd[18848]: Connection closed by 200.200.20.20 port 90002 [preauth]`

Been banging my head on this for a bit, any help much appreciated!

Comment: "Offering RSA public key: /Users/erickofman/.ssh/salsadb.pub" https://stackoverflow.com/a/29948797/13317

Comment: @Kenster My bad, I had pasted incorrect code -- I get the exact same error when using the private key, however, I've updated the post

Comment: ```debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/erickofman/.ssh/salsadb
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).```

Comment: Are there other users who are able to ssh in using keys?

Comment: Yes my coworker has been able to with a key had previously generated and added, but we walked through the same process together from scratch and now he cannot ssh in either with a new key.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: Your coworker can still log in using their previously-generated key, but not the newly-generated key which you're sure has been added to their authorized_keys file correctly? Or does their previously-generated key also not work now?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whelp, turns out that new ssh keys do not get incorporated unless a full instance restart is effected. *Not ssh server restart*, but a full instance restart (stop gcloud instance, then start gcloud instance). It doesn't say this in the documentation, good to know for future reference.

Comment: Interesting. Don't forget to mark this as the answer, per https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Per [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230909/cant-connect-to-another-user-than-root-through-ssh) make sure you're .ssh/authorized_keys in **your user's** directory.

You also want to ensure your .ssh directory and authorized_keys have the proper permissions set. (700 and 600 respectively).

```
sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't work though -- both those links point to the same site -- did you mean to post a different one for the second link?

Comment: I must've mixed up my clipboard. Removed the second one.