# Git ssh authentification problems

Tags: git, ssh, cygwin, openssh

I have problems with git authentification.
Config is

```
Host host.com 
User myuser
RSAAuthentication yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

ssh rsa-file is generated with

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

pub file is copied to server

git server ask me for passphrase - it's empty

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 149
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:AP3XfSyCKl/bvQCOxyg2JyNHSKME53YENRbWY1c+D4w
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/ESZaytseva/.ssh/id_rsa.pub':
debug2: no passphrase given, try next key
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29948797/13317

Comment: yes, it was a reason, thank you:)