# Error trying to connect to google cloud over SSH

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, ssh-keys

I'm trying to connect to Google Cloud ssh, but I'm not getting it, I get a denied permission error in the public key. I followed some internet tutorials and none worked.

chmod 0700 in the .ssh folder and the files inside it 0600

None of the options below worked.

ssh-add
eval "$ (ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~ / .ssh / id_rsa
authorized_keys

Error log:

debug1: Found key in /home/dev01/.ssh/known_hosts:2

debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent

debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS

debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks

debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received

debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received

debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs =

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey

debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/dev01/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey

debug1: No more authentication methods to try.

**Permission denied (publickey).**

Comment: "debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/dev01/.ssh/id_rsa.pub": https://stackoverflow.com/a/29948797/13317

Answer (score 0):

> This [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#createsshkeys) shows you how to control access to Linux instances by creating SSH keys and editing public SSH key metadata. After you've generated the SSH key using the ssh-keygen tool, you would need to add the key to your instance based or project-wide metadata. This [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide) will help.