# Random SSH permissions issues with Ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible, permissions

I am having a strange issues with ansible, I am trying to create an initial setup on my servers so I can use SSH keys rather than passwords, so what I am doing is for each server group, I have a path where I am creating my SSH key, using ansible authorize the key on the servers with a password prompt, so that after I won't need to use a password again unless I regenerate my keys.

I created my SSH keys via `ssh-keygen -f ./ssh/server/id_rsa`

I have my hosts file setup with the location of the SSH key like this

```
[server]
172.16.0.211

[server:vars]
ansible_user=ubuntu
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=./ssh/server/id_rsa.pub
```

I have the following in my ansible playbook

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Set authorized key for user {{ ansible_user }} copying it from current user
      authorized_key:
        user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
        state: present
        key: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ ansible_ssh_private_key_file }}') }}"
```

I am running `ansible-playbook -K -k ./ssh.yaml --verbose` so I have to enter my password first before it sets up my SSH keys, which works, it updates and I am able to run a ping using `ansible all --module-name ping` and it pings and works fine..

```
172.16.0.211 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

However randomly, if I run ping again or any other playbooks using the new SSH key..
it says

```
Failed to connect to the host via ssh: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @\r\n@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\nPermissions 0644 for './ssh/id_rsa.pub' are too open.\r\nIt is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.\r\nThis private key will be ignored.\r\nLoad key \"./ssh/server/id_rsa.pub\
```

I tried to give it permissions using `chmod 600 ./ssh/server/id_rsa.pub` but then ping now says

```
172.16.0.211 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Load key \"./ssh/server/id_rsa.pub\": invalid format\r\nubuntu@172.16.0.211: Permission denied (publickey,password).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I was actually able to get it working for a few mins.. I have it sending to multiple servers.. but its showing similar error but only for 2 of them...

```
172.16.0.212 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
172.16.0.210 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
172.16.0.211 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
172.16.0.213 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
172.16.0.214 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @\r\n@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\nPermissions 0644 for './ssh/server/id_rsa.pub' are too open.\r\nIt is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.\r\nThis private key will be ignored.\r\nLoad key \"./ssh/server/id_rsa.pub\": bad permissions\r\nubuntu@172.16.0.214: Permission denied (publickey,password).",
    "unreachable": true
}
172.16.0.215 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @\r\n@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\nPermissions 0644 for './ssh/server/id_rsa.pub' are too open.\r\nIt is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.\r\nThis private key will be ignored.\r\nLoad key \"./ssh/server/id_rsa.pub\": bad permissions\r\nubuntu@172.16.0.215: Permission denied (publickey,password).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Only way I can get it to work again, is to regenerate the key again and copy back to server again, but happens again

It doesn't feel like a permission issue, as it worked with same SSH key for the other servers.. ?

While typing this, ran it again and they all failed now.. I am still able to connect to server via password, so servers are not having issues

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Also update.. I was able to get it work again by running just the ssh.yaml playbook without recreating the SSH keys, which updated nothing.. i am starting to wonder if its something to do with caching the password prompt?

Comment: `ansible_ssh_private_key_file=./ssh/server/id_rsa.pub` https://stackoverflow.com/a/29948797/13317

Comment: Your var name contains `private` the extension of the referenced file is `.pub`. There seems to be a bit of confusion.

Comment: Hmm good point.. I might have to rethink how I set that up, I was wanting the server group to use different keys, didnt realize i was using the public key in the private variable.. good catch

Comment: Yep that seems to cleared that up.. created a ansible_ssh_public_key_file for the ssh.yaml playbook instead