Unable to fix SSH Permission denied (publickey) error
I keep getting this error whenever I try to access a server via ssh using VSCode's Remote Explorer or command line terminal.
I already checked this question, but was unable to solve the issue.
I have:

made sure that the .ssh folder and files belong to the same user using chmod and whoami
made sure that the ssh folder is 700 and key file is 600 by using chmod and stat -f "%Lp" filename
made sure the config and key files are under Users/[username]/.ssh
tried setting IdentitiesOnly and PubKeyAuthentication to "yes"
made sure the private keys file is local and the public keysfile is on the server

Is there anything else I could be missing?
Any chances I have to change something in the server side?
I am using a Mac laptop, and it is the first time setting up any remote access on this specific laptop.
I am trying to access a GCP VM instance (that also contains the ssh key).
this is the output of ssh -i ~/.ssh/private_keys_file -p port username@hostname -vv
OpenSSH_9.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/name/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname hostname is address
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to hostname [hostname] port portnumber.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/private_keys_file type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/private_keys_file-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to hostname:portnumber as 'username'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/name/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c,kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:some_different_key?
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/name/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '[hostname]:portnumber' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/name/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/name/.ssh/private_keys_file RSA SHA256:CJ9uoUi5OhdyGtue7jMFySsiVUXp0y6dlJ4YFycS17s explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/name/.ssh/private_keys_file RSA SHA256:CJ9uoUi5OhdyGtue7jMFySsiVUXp0y6dlJ4YFycS17s explicit
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
username@hostname: Permission denied (publickey).

This is the output when I try to use the remote explorer:
Host my_project_name
    HostName hostname
    User username
    Port portnumber
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_private_key_file
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    PubKeyAuthentication yes

[18:49:53.928] Log Level: 2
[18:49:53.932] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+my-project-name", attempt 1
[18:49:53.934] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true
[18:49:53.934] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": true
[18:49:53.934] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[18:49:53.934] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[18:49:53.934] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[18:49:53.934] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[18:49:53.934] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[18:49:53.934] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[18:49:53.934] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[18:49:53.934] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[18:49:53.934] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[18:49:53.935] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[18:49:53.935] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[18:49:53.935] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[18:49:53.935] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[18:49:53.938] VS Code version: 1.90.2
[18:49:53.938] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.112.0
[18:49:53.938] darwin arm64
[18:49:53.939] SSH Resolver called for host: my-project-name
[18:49:53.939] Setting up SSH remote "my-project-name"
[18:49:53.941] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/00/74r40yj568lgg9nq5q3g_3sh0000gp/T/vscode-remote-ssh-4932b980-install.lock
[18:49:53.941] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/name/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-4932b980-5437499feb04f7a586f677b155b039bc2b3669eb-0.112.0-es/data.json
[18:49:53.941] Using commit id "5437499feb04f7a586f677b155b039bc2b3669eb" and quality "stable" for server
[18:49:53.943] Install and start server if needed
[18:49:53.947] PATH: /Users/name/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.1/bin:/Users/name/.npm-packages/bin:/Users/name/.bun/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
[18:49:53.947] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[18:49:53.970] > OpenSSH_9.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6

[18:49:53.971] askpass server listening on /var/folders/00/74r40yj568lgg9nq5q3g_3sh0000gp/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-685034522e84a74c430df959bf8a94ccc8cc51b0.sock
[18:49:53.972] Spawning local server with {"serverId":1,"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/00/74r40yj568lgg9nq5q3g_3sh0000gp/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-4ddffc100b702667efcf8eceaedbc57fed8a3b5a.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","52070","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","my-project-name"],"serverDataFolderName":".vscode-server","dataFilePath":"/Users/name/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-4932b980-5437499feb04f7a586f677b155b039bc2b3669eb-0.112.0-es/data.json"}
[18:49:53.972] Local server env: {"SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.5FLI42FeEC/Listeners","SHELL":"/bin/zsh","DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/Users/name/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.112.0/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin)","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS":"","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/Users/name/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.112.0/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/var/folders/00/74r40yj568lgg9nq5q3g_3sh0000gp/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-685034522e84a74c430df959bf8a94ccc8cc51b0.sock"}
[18:49:53.972] Spawned 73935
[18:49:54.064] > local-server-1> Running ssh connection command: ssh -v -T -D 52070 -o ConnectTimeout=15 my-project-name
[18:49:54.066] > local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=73944
[18:49:54.077] stderr> OpenSSH_9.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
[18:49:54.168] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:some_different_key?
[18:49:54.298] stderr> username@hostname: Permission denied (publickey).
[18:49:54.299] > local-server-1> ssh child died, shutting down
[18:49:54.306] Local server exit: 0
[18:49:54.306] Received install output: local-server-1> Running ssh connection command: ssh -v -T -D 52070 -o ConnectTimeout=15 my-project-name
local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=73944
OpenSSH_9.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:some_different_ssh_key?
username@hostname: Permission denied (publickey).
local-server-1> ssh child died, shutting down

[18:49:54.309] Resolver error: Error: Permission denied (publickey).
    at g.Create (/Users/name/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.112.0/out/extension.js:2:499918)
    at /Users/name/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.112.0/out/extension.js:2:496392
    at t.handleInstallOutput (/Users/name/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.112.0/out/extension.js:2:497162)
    at e (/Users/name/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.112.0/out/extension.js:2:558422)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /Users/name/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.112.0/out/extension.js:2:580377
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (/Users/name/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.112.0/out/extension.js:2:584036)
    at async /Users/name/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.112.0/out/extension.js:2:555127
    at async T (/Users/name/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.112.0/out/extension.js:2:553178)
    at async t.resolveWithLocalServer (/Users/name/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.112.0/out/extension.js:2:554667)
    at async k (/Users/name/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.112.0/out/extension.js:2:577548)
    at async t.resolve (/Users/name/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.112.0/out/extension.js:2:581407)
    at async /Users/name/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.112.0/out/extension.js:2:848023
[18:49:54.313] ------

this is the output of namei -mo $(realpath ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ) on the server side:
 drwxr-xr-x root    root    /
 drwxr-xr-x root    root    home
 drwxr-x--- username username username
 drwx------ username username .ssh
 -rw------- username username authorized_keys

Running journalctl -u ssh -ef on the server printed No journal files were found..
This was the output for running tail -f /var/log/auth.log:
Jul  2 09:37:00 cs-1091963627082-default sshd[346]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user username(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jul  2 09:37:00 cs-1091963627082-default sshd[346]: pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to connect to system bus: No such file or directory
Jul  2 09:37:00 cs-1091963627082-default sshd[367]: reprocess config line 45: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Jul  2 09:37:00 cs-1091963627082-default sshd[367]: reprocess config line 52: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
Jul  2 09:37:01 cs-1091963627082-default sudo:  username : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/username ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/touch /var/run/google/devshell/38357
Jul  2 09:37:01 cs-1091963627082-default sshd[367]: Accepted publickey for username from 127.0.0.1 port 44678 ssh2: ECDSA SHA256:Og9M7KmC/Jk0ccfAdxaOwWgUNMkGuZxvvkCQXMCQsto
Jul  2 09:37:01 cs-1091963627082-default sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1000)
Jul  2 09:37:01 cs-1091963627082-default sshd[367]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user username(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jul  2 09:37:01 cs-1091963627082-default sshd[367]: pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to connect to system bus: No such file or directory
Jul  2 09:37:01 cs-1091963627082-default sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user rootJul  2 09:41:45 cs-1091963627082-default sshd[744]: rexec line 30: Deprecated option UsePrivilegeSeparation
Jul  2 09:41:45 cs-1091963627082-default sshd[744]: rexec line 33: Deprecated option KeyRegenerationInterval
Jul  2 09:41:45 cs-1091963627082-default sshd[744]: rexec line 34: Deprecated option ServerKeyBits
Jul  2 09:41:45 cs-1091963627082-default sshd[744]: rexec line 45: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Jul  2 09:41:45 cs-1091963627082-default sshd[744]: rexec line 52: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
Jul  2 09:41:45 cs-1091963627082-default sshd[744]: error: kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters
Jul  2 09:41:45 cs-1091963627082-default sshd[744]: banner exchange: Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 60734: invalid format

Not sure if this is me connecting to the shell from the GCS website.
The authorized_keys file should be containing the public keys:
$ cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAA......=

After following the instructions on step 4 I got the following:
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:some_fingerprint.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
username@localhost: Permission denied (publickey).

I guess this makes sure that it is a server side issue?

Show the output of ssh -vv ...

@jeb I added the output

are you trying to connect to root user?

@jeb sorry I am not that familiar with ssh and user terminal users, am I supposed to? I am guessing I should connect to "username", are the authorized_keys supposed to go elsewhere?

The filename.pub file on the server is useless. On the server only the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file is important, that file should contain your public key as one line.
Use ssh -i ~/.ssh/<private_key> ... because -i expects a private not a public key

@jeb thanks for the info! I tried creating a ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on the server with the public key, restarted the server and called ssh -i ~/.ssh/<private_key> instead but still got the same error

Then you should update the output of ssh -vv, you could also look on the server into journalctl -u ssh -ef while trying to connect

ssh -i ~/.ssh/filename.pub ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/29948797/13317

The credentials for .ssh don't need to be so strict. Mine has 755 and works. The private key must be 600, and the public one is 644.

@jeb I updated the question with the output after changing the files

On the server you could try sudo journalctl ... or tail -f /var/log/auth.log.
Are you sure that ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the server contains your public key?

@jeb thanks for sticking with this issue, I updated the question and also added the output of when I try using the remote explorer on VSCode


You should check the output of ssh -vv.
Is your private key used and offered?
Do you connect to the correct server on the correct port?

You could check (on the server) if all directories have the proper rights/owner.
Because ssh doesn't use authorized_keys, if any of the parent directories have permissions that are too open.
namei -mo $(realpath ~/.ssh/authorized_keys )

You could look into the journal (on the server) while connecting from the client
sudo journalctl --unit ssh --pager-end --follow

As a simple test you could create a new key on the server and try a local connect


ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 -N ""
cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh localhost

If that works, copy the id_ed25519 file to your client and try it from there

Thanks for the help! I added the output of the command you gave me and ssh -vvv to the question
